# Why is oracle instant client so slow on OSX?

Tags: networking, macos, performance, database

I have both a PC and Mac environment setup to connect to the same Oracle server. Both are using Oracle instant client 11.2.0.4 and are on the same network. Both machines are similarly configured (e.g., 16GB, flash drive, network connections, etc.).

When I try to execute a select from a relatively small table using SQLPlus, it takes ~2ms on my PC while it takes over 2 seconds on my Mac. I've attempted to dig into the differences using the Oracle trace files and other tools, but have not found anything that I am doing incorrectly.

Google searches have not yielded any helpful results. Is this just a dead end for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with the network connection. Although I thought I had validated my Ethernet network connection was live and valid, the communication was preferring the wireless connection. Once I resolved this problem, I received results comparable to the PC environment.